# Can I take a screen capture from an Android app by using a service?

Tags: android, service, screenshot

I was wondering if there is a way to take a screenshot of the current screen inside the mobile phone using a service (I know how to do it through DDMS though)

Comment: So you want another method other than using DDMS?

Comment: Yeah... I was thinking of something like a screenshot button like on computers... Just dumps a screenshot onto the SDCard or something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without root access.

Comment: Oh... that is interesting... How would I do that with root access? I can at least try it out on the emulator...

Comment: Since it requires root access, the answer won't be in the SDK.  I would look at Linux system utilities that the device has installed, and figure out what command line string to execute on the device.

Comment: I don't have any source that does this sorry, Koushik Dutta made an application I believed he used a hack in the source to trigger the same mechanism that DDMS uses to take it's screen shots.. he has a page up about the app, you will probably find a lot more information on xda developers (android development forum section).  Here is the link I was talking about: http://www.koushikdutta.com/2008/11/android-screenshot-application.html

Comment: Looks cool... Thanks... I will dig through the code... Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Just for encouragement I would like to say that on Android Developer Challenge 2 there is an application called 'drocap' that does exactly this - takes screenshots on the phone. This is running on my stock european Hero, so no root access required.

But I have no idea how it works. So - keep looking ;)

Comment: Could you point me to the source of this app? Or do they even have their source out there?